# how to parse a list with foldr in SML

Tags: sml

Let's say I have a list:

```
type myList = (string * int) list;
```

And I want to find a specific element of this list using foldr, so something like:

```
fun findElement (element : string) (list : myList) : int result =
 if needed_element is equal current_list_element then return current_list_element
 else continue checking the rest of the list
 else return -1
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Writing pseudocode can be really helpful.

What can also be very helpful is clearly determining the type of this function, e.g.:

```
val findElement = fn : string -> myList -> ?
```

What type should the function return? In your pseudocode you write `int result`, but `result` isn't available as a built-in type constructor in Standard ML. So what should it be? `int`? What if there isn't an element that matches, how do you differentiate between any particular result and "no result"? What are your options?

---

Try and solve this problem without using `foldr` first.

Since scanning a list means recursing along its structure, you can write this function using pattern matching where you divide the pattern into one that matches an empty list and one that matches a non-empty list:

```
fun lookup needle [] = ?
  | lookup needle ((key, value) :: haystack) =
      if ?
      then ?
      else ?
```

- The condition has to compare `needle` with something for each pair until one matches. How do you compare two values for equality in SML?
- When the condition is satisfied, it isn't necessary to perform further recursion, so a value can be returned. How does one return something in SML?
- When the condition isn't satisfied, the search continues by `lookup` calling itself on `haystack`. Calling oneself means referring to `lookup` within the body after "`else`". Exactly what arguments should it call itself with?

---

Having an understanding of basic recursive functions is prerequisite to understanding `foldr`. At this point, try and read about `foldr`. I cannot find any good open material specifically on this, so I would look up any book-shaped learning material you have available.

In terms of challenges associated with expressing `lookup` with `foldr`:

- `foldr` does not stop recursion when an element is found.
- You can stop it by throwing an exception and catching it. This is a little tricky.
- You can let it loop to the end and keep the first element found. This is a little inefficient.

A template might look like:

```
fun lookup needle haystack =
    foldr (fn ((key, value), acc) => ?) ? haystack
```

Or you may name the anonymous function `fn ... => ?` locally:

```
fun lookup needle haystack =
    let fun go ((key, value), acc) = ?
    in foldr go ? haystack
    end
```

Here `?` refers to a value of the type that `lookup` returns.

That type can be the same regardless of whether you use manual recursion or `foldr`.